# "В ту же цену" — какой статус у этого выражения? Оно разговорное или вполне литературное?

Tags: стилистика, цельное-выражение

У классиков оно встречается, но всего [три примера](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D1%83%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83) нашел в Нацкорпусе.

Answer (score 1):

Если литературно выглядит

> Но иногда мне любопытно узнать ― в какую цену? [Ю.И. Визбор. Завтрак
> с видом на Эльбрус (1983)],

то «в ту же цену» как ответное, в соответствующем контексте, — вполне литературно.

Comment: Считаете ли Вы, что в остальных случаях это выражение не будет литературным? (Я действительно не понял это из ответа.)

Comment: Остальных случаях? Каких же? Нужна конкретика. В тех примерах, что у Артёма  из НК, контекст понятен: цена прежде была названа и известна. «В ту же цену» как продолжение рассуждения литературно.

Comment: Спасибо, shampar! Задал вопрос и в магазине услышал как раз "В какую цену..?" :)

Answer (score 0):

[Словарь управления](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0&all=x) говорит и "ценой в десять рублей", и "ценой десять рублей", но отмечает, что второй вариант встречается чаще. Думаю, что выражение в вопросе из той же серии.

Comment: Спасибо, grizzly!

Comment: Раз уж словари не против, попробую обосновать. _В какую цену_ = _во что_ обходится (то или иное приобретение): "что" конкретизируется, предлог остаётся.